# Task with braces, brackets and parenthesis

Tags: c++, regex, algorithm

Task is to check if given string contains balanced sets of `{}`, `[]` and `()`.

For example, `check("{[}]")` must return `false`, and `check("{[]()}")` must return `true`, etc.

The solution:

```
bool check(const std::string & s)
{
    constexpr auto brackets1 = "()";
    constexpr auto brackets2 = "[]";
    constexpr auto brackets3 = "{}";
    constexpr size_t brackets_pair_size = 2;
    constexpr auto brackets = "()[]{}";

    std::string s2;

    for (auto & c : s) 
    {
        if (strchr(brackets, c) != nullptr) 
        {
            s2 += c;
        }
    }

    auto brackets1_pos{ std::string::npos };
    auto brackets2_pos{ std::string::npos };
    auto brackets3_pos{ std::string::npos };

    while ((brackets1_pos = s2.find(brackets1)) != std::string::npos ||
           (brackets2_pos = s2.find(brackets2)) != std::string::npos ||
           (brackets3_pos = s2.find(brackets3)) != std::string::npos
           ) 
    {
        if (brackets1_pos != std::string::npos) {
            s2.erase(brackets1_pos, brackets_pair_size);
            continue;
        }

        if (brackets2_pos != std::string::npos) {
            s2.erase(brackets2_pos, brackets_pair_size);
            continue;
        }

        if (brackets3_pos != std::string::npos) {
            s2.erase(brackets3_pos, brackets_pair_size);
            continue;
        }
    }

    return s2.empty();
}
```

Idea is:
- copy all pars, brackets and braces to another string, 
- remove pairs of brackets from second string,
- check if second string is empty.

Is there any way to improve the algorithm?

May be some universal regex?

Comment: Regular expressions are not really good with nesting constructs. Also, I this would fit better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, didn't know of that community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking for **nested** braces seems like a natural case for `std::stack`. Push braces onto the stack as you iterate over the input and test for correct matches when you see a closing brace.

```
bool check(const std::string &expression) // balanced and nested?
{
    std::stack<char> stack;

    for (auto ch : expression) {
        switch (ch) {
        case '(': // open parenthesis
        case '<': // open angle
        case '[': // open bracket
        case '{': // open brace
            stack.push(ch);
            break;
        case ')': // close parenthesis
            if (stack.empty() || stack.top() != '(') return false;
            stack.pop();
            break;
        case '>': // close angle
            if (stack.empty() || stack.top() != '<') return false;
            stack.pop();
            break;
        case ']': // close bracket
            if (stack.empty() || stack.top() != '[') return false;
            stack.pop();
            break;
        case '}': // close brace
            if (stack.empty() || stack.top() != '{') return false;
            stack.pop();
            break;
        }
    }
    return stack.empty(); // no unmatched braces left?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This task is not doable with a regex because they have no memory and cannot remember the depth of parenthesing.

You should use a parser, probably a [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), to do the task.

The grammar would look like this (not tested):

```
input: /* empty */
     | expr input

expr: paren-expr
    | bracket-expr
    | curly-bracket-expr

paren-expr: '(' input ')'

bracket-expr: '[' input ']'

curly-bracket-expr: '{' input '}'
```

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>


class parenthesis_checker {

  template <class It>
  It parse_open_close(It first, It last, char op, char cl) const {
    if(op != *first) return first;

    It r = parse_input(first+1, last);
    if(last == r) return first;
    if(cl != *r)  return first;

    return r+1;
  }

  template <class It>
  It parse_expr(It first, It last) const {
    It r = parse_open_close(first, last, '(', ')');
    if(r != first) return r;

    r = parse_open_close(first, last, '[', ']');
    if(r != first) return r;

    r = parse_open_close(first, last, '{', '}');
    if(r != first) return r;

    return first;
  }

  template <class It>
  It parse_input(It first, It last) const {
    while(first != last) {
      It r = parse_expr(first, last);
      if(r == first) return r;
      first = r;
    }
    return first;
  }

public:
  template <class It>
  bool operator()(It first, It last) const {
    return last==parse_input(first, last);
  }

  template <class Cont>
  bool operator()(Cont value) const {
    return (*this)(value.begin(), value.end());
  }

  bool operator()(const char* str) const {
    return (*this)(std::string(str));
  }
};


int main() {
  parenthesis_checker check;

  std::cout << check("{[}]") << std::endl;
  std::cout << check("{[]()}") << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems overcomplicated and I have to admit that I didn't try too hard to understand it but it is not obvious to me that it is even correct.
A very simple solution to this problem is to create a stack and go through the string pushing opening parentheses to the stack and popping from the stack on closing parentheses (when you pop you have to check that the opening and closing parentheses match).

It is unfortunately impossible to solve this problem with regular expressions as the language of well balanced parentheses is not [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the matching brackets by following simple piece of code.

```
int bracketMatcher(string s)
{
    list<int> *countsList = new list<int>();
    string expression = s;
    int correctBrackets = 1;

    for (int index = 0; index < expression.size(); index++) {
        char ch = expression[index];
        if (ch == '(')
        {
            countsList->push_back(index);
        }
        else if (ch == ')')
        {
            if (countsList->size() == 0)
            {
                correctBrackets = 0;
                break;
            }
            countsList->pop_back();
        }
    }
    if (countsList->size() != 0)
    {
        correctBrackets = 0;
    }
    return correctBrackets;
}
```

or if you want to find a specific bracket type then can also use following function.

```
bool bracketMatcher(string s , char c)
{
    list<int> *countsList = new list<int>();
    string expression = s;
    bool correctBrackets = true;

    char secondCh =' ';
    switch (c) {
        case '(': // open parenthesis
            secondCh = ')';
            break;
        case '<': // open angle
            secondCh = '>';
            break;
        case '[': // open bracket
            secondCh = ']';
            break;
        case '{': // open brace
            secondCh = '}';
            break;
        default:

            break;
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < expression.size(); index++) {
        char ch = expression[index];
        if (ch == c)
        {
            countsList->push_back(index);
        }
        else if (ch == secondCh)
        {
            if (countsList->size() == 0)
            {
                correctBrackets = false;
                break;
            }
            countsList->pop_back();
        }
    }
    if (countsList->size() != 0)
    {
        correctBrackets = false;
    }
    return correctBrackets;
}
int main() {

    string s  = " ((hello ) (()) llll {}word <aaa>(aad))";
    //always specify the opening bracket here

    bool parenthesisMatch = bracketMatcher(s,'(');
    bool angleBracketsMatch = bracketMatcher(s,'<');
    bool bracketMatch = bracketMatcher(s,'[');
    bool bracesMatch = bracketMatcher(s, '{');

    if(parenthesisMatch && angleBracketsMatch && bracketMatch && bracesMatch) {
        cout << "found all matching brackets" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "could not find all matching brackets" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're leaking memory in both examples. There's no good reason to use `new` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please tell me what is wrong with my code it's always giving NO

```
string isBalanced(string s) {
stack<char> comp;
char temp;
int i;
for(i=s.size()-1;(s[i]=='}' ) || (s[i]==')' ) || (s[i]==']');i--)
{
    comp.push(s[i]);
}

if(comp.size()!=i+1)
return ("NO");

while(!comp.empty() && i>=0)
{
    temp=comp.top();
    if(temp!=s[i])
    return ("NO");
    comp.pop();
    i--;
}

return("YES");
}
```